# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: oracle

Cannot export Generate Excel Report more than 12000 records using Java Stored Procedure in  Oracle Data base.

```
HSSFWorkbook resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
```

Comment: we have increase the Heap Size too but the problem Still Exist

Comment: See Oracle startup parameter JAVA_POOL_SIZE

Comment: Thanks for your response ,v$parameter returned 0 for JAVA_POOL_SIZE.what should it be?Please let us know .

Comment: v$sgainfo returns 64MB for Java Pool Size

Comment: I think zero means minimal or default value. But I'm not sure in this case I doubt it can be changed online. Try to execute as DBA `alter system set JAVA_POOL_SIZE=1G scope=both;` If it fails then execute `alter system set JAVA_POOL_SIZE=1G scope=spfile;` and restart the database.

Comment: JAVA_POOL_SIZE is increased to 512 MB, But still the problem Exist.Kindly assist me in this.